# VBA Outlook macro for loop error

Tags: vba, for-loop, outlook

I have written a Outlook macro which is suppose to: Check the subject of unread emails in the inbox, for a PO number. If it finds a PO number, it looks for an associated email adress in an excel file. (Our seller's email), If it finds an email adress, the unread email is forwarded to that address, and the mail marked as read.

The code works fine the first time it encounters an unread email adress with a PO number in the subject. The problem is that the code does not continue with the for loop. Instead I get an error message saying "The element has been moved or deleted". I am 99% sure the problem is that the for loop does not continue the way it should after first encountering a mail that fufills all criterias. Never the less I will post the entire code just to be sure. As always any time used looking at my problems is very greatly appreciated!

```
Sub ForwardMail()

On Error GoTo eh:

'Initalizing Excel related variables and instances'
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Application.Visible = True
Set XlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("My path")

Dim Mailadress As Variant
Dim PoSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Set PoSheet = XlBook.Sheets("SheetName")
'End  Initalizing Excel related variables and instances

'Initalizing Outlook related variables and instances
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim folder As MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object
Dim MailToForward As MailItem

Set ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set folder = ns.Folders("Example@mail.com").Folders("Inbox")
'Slutt initialisering Outlook relatert

Dim PoNumber As Double

'Loop through the items in the inbox folder
For Each item In folder.Items
    DoEvents
    If (item.Class = olMail) And (item.UnRead) Then
        'Find PO number from the subject
        PoNumber = CDbl(FinnPo(item.Subject))

        'If Po number is found, find email adress, using PO number
        If PoNumber <> 0 Then

            'Find email adress in excel file
            Mailadress = xlApp.VLookup(PoNumber, PoSheet.Range("C:D"), 2, False)

            'If mailadress variable is not an error, forward unread email to mailadress.
            If IsError(Mailadress) = False Then
                Set MailToForward = item.Forward
                MailToForward.To = Mailadress
                MailToForward.Send

                'Set mail property as read
                MailToForward.UnRead = False

            Else

            End If

        End If

    End If

Next

XlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

MsgBox "Macro finished"

Exit Sub

eh:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number

End Sub

Function FinnPo(Subject As String) As String

    Dim find As String
    Find = "4500"

    Dim Location As Integer
    Location = InStr(Subject, Find)

    If Location <> 0 Then
        FinnPo = Mid(Subject, Location, 10)
    Else
        FinnPo = "0"
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a lot of googeling finally solved my code problem. The fact that I was sending the mail item `MailToForward` meant that the item stopped existing. I therefore Had to move the initializing of the variable into the loop. I also had to mark the `item.Unread` after sending, not the MailItem that had ceased to exist at that point. Hope that helpe anyone else with a similar problem: MailItems stop existing after being sent.